# Way to make jqGrid responsive on web browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am new in jqGrid and I need that grid will be resized on resizing the window of the web browser. I have applied   `autowidth : true;` , `shrinkToFit: true;` in grid but that is not working.

Setting of CSS `width : 100%` is the only one implementation, but it's not good in case of jqGrid
which set `width` in `px` explicitly on many its internal structures.

what would be the perfect way to solve it ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

jqGrid uses fixed `width` value on many internal structures (divs, tables and so on). So one can't just set CSS `width : 100%`. Nevertheless there are another way to do the same. One can register `resize` event handler on `window` object and to call `setGridWidth` explicitly. The method adjust **all internals structures** of jqGrid to new width. So it would be clean method.

If you use `autowidth: true` then jqGrid set the width of jqGrid to the width of it's parent only once. Inside of `$(window).resize` handler we can get *new* (the current) width of the parent and reset the value of grid `width`. The corresponding code will be the following

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
```

I used `$("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid")` instead of `$("#list")` because jqGrid build some dives *over* the main `<table>` element. `$("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid")` gives as *the outer* div which include all the elements of the grid.

[The modified fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejpn9/4/) demonstrates the code live.

Comment: the pager element is not responsive in this demo, i think we need to add reference to that.

Comment: @Harshit: It's depend on how exactly you define "responsive". Additionally the behavior of the pager and the navigator bar is changed in more resent versions (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Redesign-of-the-structure-of-Navigator-Bar-of-the-pagers)). [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) have mush better behavior. See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejpn9/56/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/7/). the last demo uses `"hidden-xs"` class of Bootstrap for the last column and the column will be hide/show depend on the width of grid.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and this solution worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: You are welcome! [Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/26/) shows other possibilities of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork which I develop: the properties `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` from the last column the demo uses Bootrsrap class, which hide the column if the resolution of the page will be low.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a css you can use to make grid responsive: https://github.com/guylando/Responsive-jqGrid/blob/master/Responsive-jqGrid.css

Its faster than using javascript in my opinion.

Here is the css code:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pager-control, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pager-control {
  height: auto;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="_toppager_center"], .ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="pager_center"] {
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="_toppager_left"], .ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="pager_left"] {
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto;

}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="_toppager_right"], .ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="pager_right"] {
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view.table-responsive, .ui-jqgrid, .ui-jqgrid-pager,
.ui-jqgrid-toppager, .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    width: auto !important;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="_toppager_left"], .ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="pager_left"],
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="_toppager_center"], .ui-jqgrid .ui-pager-control td[id$="pager_center"] {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This code solved my issue for an older desktop's screen display.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffK Glad it helped. Give me +1? :)

Comment: This does nothing for the columns... they still appear squished.

Answer (score 0):

Add to method below to  beforeEvent of jqgrid......

### function

```
function responsive_jqgrid(jqgrid) {
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view > div').eq(1).addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '').css('min-height', '0');
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view > div').eq(2).addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '').css('min-height', '0');
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-sdiv').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
    jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-pager').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following code but observed that it did not provide any scroller for responsive devices. Hence decided to customise the JQGRID stylesheet:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
```

Please find my hack for making JQ Grid properly responsive

/**** JQ grid responsiveness ***/

```
#gview_jqgrid, div#myPager {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv, .ui-jqgrid-htable {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid-bdiv, #jqgrid {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox {padding-right:0 !important;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
div#gbox_jqgrid { width: 100% !important; overflow-x: scroll; margin-bottom: 80px !important;}
```

Add this to the custom stylesheet & get set to view the JQGrid fully responsive!

Any other suggestions will be most welcomed. Try it out & Enjoy!

Comment: Did you see the fiddle attached to the accepted answer?  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejpn9/4/)

Comment: The columns are not visible in the mobile device and there is no scroll bar for responsive devices, Could you please provide a proper script for the scroll? I think script code will work instead of css.