# Make JqGrid width fluid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Corrected Code :

```
<script>
    var $grid = $("#list2");
    emptyMsgDiv = $("<div><span style='color:red; text-align:center;font-size:18px;display:block;'>No Workorder Found</span></div>");
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'server.php',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['WO#','Status','Customer Name','Salesman', 'Created Date', 'WO Total', 'Notes', 'Edit'],  
        colModel:[ 
               {name:'id',index:'id', align:"center"}, 
               {name:'status1',index:'status1', align:"center", width:100}, 
               {name:'status2',index:'status2', align:"center", width:50}, 
               {name:'status3',index:'status3', align:"center"}, 
               {name:'result',index:'result', align:"center", sortable:false}          
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'Invoice.id',
        viewrecords: true,
        height:'100%',
        autowidth:true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: '100%',
        loadComplete: function() {
             var ts = this;
             if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                 $(this).hide();
                 emptyMsgDiv.show();
             } else {
                 $(this).show();
                 emptyMsgDiv.hide();
             }
        }
    });
    emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter($grid.parent());
    </script>
```

Here is the code I have for my JqGrid :

```
<script>
var $grid = $("#list2");
emptyMsgDiv = $("<div><span style='color:red; text-align:center;font-size:18px;display:block;'>No Workorder Found</span></div>");
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['WO#','Status','Customer Name','Salesman', 'Created Date', 'WO Total', 'Notes', 'Edit'],  
    colModel:[ 
           {name:'id',index:'id', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'status1',index:'status1', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'status2',index:'status2', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'status3',index:'status3', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'result',index:'result', align:"center", sortable:false}          
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'Invoice.id',
    viewrecords: true,
    height:'100%',
    sortorder: "desc",
    height: '100%',
    loadComplete: function() {
         var ts = this;
         if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
             $(this).hide();
             emptyMsgDiv.show();
         } else {
             $(this).show();
             emptyMsgDiv.hide();
         }
    }
});
emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter($grid.parent());
</script>
```

I am trying to make the colModel fluid width for the page, I am able to change the width manually for each of the columns as in the following tidbit :

```
{name:'status1',index:'status1', align:"center", width:50}
```

However, I can not define percentages, or seem to figure out how to do fluid width.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you additionally to remove all `index` properties from the `colModel` items and to set common properties inside of `cmTemplate`: `colModel: [{name: 'id'}, {name: 'status1'}, {name: 'status2'}, {name: 'status3'}, {name: 'result', sortable: false}], cmTemplate: { align: 'center' }`. The second `height:'100%'` option (you inserted it twice) should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should add `autowidth: true` option, which sets the initial width of the grid to the width of outer container on the HTML page. It will force resizing of all columns proportional of the value of `width` property in `colModel`. Because you don't specify any `width` property then the default `150` value will be used. In case of resizing it means just that you specified *the same* width for all columns. If you need to hold some fixed width for some columns, for example for the column which have `formatter: "actions"` (which displays two editing icons in the grid), then you can add `fixed: true` to the column.

To resize the grid every time after the web browser window or the outer div will be resized you can use the following code

```js
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    var newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
}).trigger("resize");
```

(see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036623/315935)).

Additional features exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with renaming jqGrid to [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and making it commercial. The demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/19/ uses `<div class="container">` as the outer div of jqGrid and to add `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` bootstrap classes (see [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)) to less important column `ComboDuration` of the demo. As the result, the column will be made automatically hidden/visible on resizing of the grid. It could be very helpful to produce good results on mobile devices with low pixel resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it fill the page using the following :

autowidth: true,

I also set minimum custom widths for a few of the columns as listed above