# jqGrid: Responsive view of grid as datatable view on mobile/tablet.. is it posible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid, responsive

In data-table grid is responsive on mobile/tablet, where last columns(you can see in image - salary column) are hiding as resizing.

[image]

So this can be achievable (same as or something different way -no horizontal scrollbar in responsive view) with jqGrid?

Right now i have no idea about it done with jqGrid or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25036623/3115653) is closest you'll get in making you jqgrid responsive.

But the feature to toggle some columns visiblity is really not there.

Answer (score 0):

[Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports `labelClasses` property, which can be set in `colModel` additionally with `classes` property. You can use `hidden-XX` classes of Bootstrap (see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes))

```
classes: "hidden-xs",
labelClasses: "hidden-xs"
```

to hide the column for extra small/small/ledium or large devices. You can resize the window on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/45/ to see the results.